# keycloak not starting with AWS RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, keycloak

I am trying to setup keycloak on AWS EC2 instance and using AWS RDS mysql 5.7 instance as backend database. I have downloaded mysql jdbc drivers and gave the rds endpoint to point to RDS db instance in standalone-ha.xml file. I am getting some errors

`module.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar" />
  </resources>

  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

`standalone-ha.xml`:

```xml
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://xxxx.amazonrds:3306/keycloak?useSSL=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true</connection-url>
  <driver>mysql</driver>
  <pool>
    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
  </pool>
  <security>
    <user-name>xxx</user-name>
    <password>xxx</password>
  </security>
  <validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
  </validation>
  <statement>
    <track-statements>true</track-statements>
  </statement>
  <timeout>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>6000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <allocation-retry>3</allocation-retry>
  </timeout>
</datasource>

<drivers>
  <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
  </driver>
 </drivers>
```

I am getting this error:

```
=========================================================================
07:49:06,742 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0114: Failed to load datasource class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
=========================================================================
07:49:17,639 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
=====================
07:49:17,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
07:49:17,681 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
07:49:17,736 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
07:49:17,740 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
07:49:17,746 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
07:49:17,751 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
07:49:17,759 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8443
07:49:17,822 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.18.Final
07:49:17,856 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) RESTEASY008550: Unable to find CDI supporting ValidatorFactory. Using default ValidatorFactory
07:49:18,184 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'
07:49:18,186 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/auth' from server 'default-server'
07:49:18,234 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0008: Undertow AJP listener ajp suspending
07:49:18,235 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0007: Undertow AJP listener ajp stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8009
07:49:18,236 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MODCLUSTER000002: Initiating mod_cluster shutdown
07:49:18,237 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
07:49:18,247 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
07:49:18,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
07:49:18,257 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
07:49:18,258 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
07:49:18,258 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
07:49:18,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped keys cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,274 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.1.0.Final stopping
07:49:18,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authorization cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,269 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped clientSessions cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineClientSessions cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped loginFailures cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped realms cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped sessions cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped work cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineSessions cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped actionTokens cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authenticationSessions cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,261 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped users cache from keycloak container
07:49:18,288 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
07:49:18,293 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment keycloak-server.war (runtime-name: keycloak-server.war) in 610ms
07:49:18,303 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
07:49:18,319 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd.java:86)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:527)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:448)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:401)
    atorg.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: any advise to fix this issue will be helpful for me.

Comment: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/unable-to-connect-to-external-database-aws-rds/3355